# Parsing tags in string

Tags: regex, string, parsing, analysis

I'm trying to parse a string with custom tags like this

```
[color value=0x000000]This house is [wave][color value=0xFF0000]haunted[/color][/wave]. 
I've heard about ghosts [shake]screaming[/shake] here after midnight.[/color]
```

I've figured out what regexps to use

```
/\[color value=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/gs
/\[wave\](.*?)\[\/wave\]/gs
/\[shake\](.*?)\[\/shake\]/gs
```

But the thing is - I need to get correct ranges (startIndex, endIndex) of those groups in result string so I could apply them correctly. And that's where I feel completely lost, because everytime I replace tags there's always a chance for indexes to mess up. It gets espesically hard for nested tags.

So input is a string

```
[color value=0x000000]This house is [wave][color value=0xFF0000]haunted[/color][/wave]. 
I've heard about ghosts [shake]screaming[/shake] here after midnight.[/color]
```

And in output I want to get something like

```
Apply color 0x000000 from 0 to 75
Apply wave from 14 to 20
Apply color 0xFF0000 from 14 to 20
Apply shake from 46 to 51
```

Notice that's indices match to result string.

How do I parse it?

Comment: Still not fully clear .. give sample input and expected output

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman updated

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: it's ActionScript

Comment: @BlueMonkMN if there's no need in regular expressions, I would also like to know how to make it

Comment: Actually I tried implementing a solution without regular expressions, and it turns out that regular expressions do eliminate a lot of the work, but it's still tricky. I think the solution that includes regular expressions will be somewhat simpler in the end, so I will show that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with ActionScript, but this C# code shows one solution using regular expressions. Rather than match specific tags, I used a regular expression that can match any tag. And instead of trying to make a regular expression that matches the whole start and end tag including the text in between (which I think is impossible with nested tags), I made the regular expression just match a start *OR* end tag, then did some extra processing to match up the start and end tags and remove them from the string keeping the essential information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      string data = "[color value=0x000000]This house is [wave][color value=0xFF0000]haunted[/color][/wave]. " +
                    "I've heard about ghosts [shake]screaming[/shake] here after midnight.[/color]";

      ParsedData result = ParseData(data);
      foreach (TagInfo t in result.tags)
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.attributeName))
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Apply {0} from {1} to {2}", t.name, t.start, t.start + t.length - 1);
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Apply {0} {1}={2} from {3} to {4}", t.name, t.attributeName, t.attributeValue, t.start, t.start + t.length - 1);
         }
         Console.WriteLine(result.data);
         Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}\n", new string(' ', t.start), new string('-', t.length));
      }
   }

   static ParsedData ParseData(string data)
   {
      List<TagInfo> tagList = new List<TagInfo>();
      Regex reTag = new Regex(@"\[(\w+)(\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*([^\]]+))?\]|\[(\/\w+)\]");
      Match m = reTag.Match(data);

      // Phase 1 - Collect all the start and end tags, noting their position in the original data string
      while (m.Success)
      {
         if (m.Groups[1].Success) // Matched a start tag
         {
            tagList.Add(new TagInfo()
            {
               name = m.Groups[1].Value,
               attributeName = m.Groups[3].Value,
               attributeValue = m.Groups[4].Value,
               tagLength = m.Groups[0].Length,
               start = m.Groups[0].Index
            });
         }
         else if (m.Groups[5].Success)
         {
            tagList.Add(new TagInfo()
            {
               name = m.Groups[5].Value,
               tagLength = m.Groups[0].Length,
               start = m.Groups[0].Index
            });
         }
         m = m.NextMatch();
      }

      // Phase 2 - match end tags to start tags
      List<TagInfo> unmatched = new List<TagInfo>();
      foreach (TagInfo t in tagList)
      {
         if (t.name.StartsWith("/"))
         {
            for (int i = unmatched.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
               if (unmatched[i].name == t.name.Substring(1))
               {
                  t.otherEnd = unmatched[i];
                  unmatched[i].otherEnd = t;
                  unmatched.Remove(unmatched[i]);
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         else
         {
            unmatched.Add(t);
         }
      }

      int subtractLength = 0;
      // Phase 3 - Remove tags from the string, updating start positions and calculating length in the process
      foreach (TagInfo t in tagList.ToArray())
      {
         t.start -= subtractLength;
         // If this is an end tag, calculate the length for the corresponding start tag,
         // and remove the end tag from the tag list.
         if (t.otherEnd.start < t.start)
         {
            t.otherEnd.length = t.start - t.otherEnd.start;
            tagList.Remove(t);
         }
         // Keep track of how many characters in tags have been removed from the string so far
         subtractLength += t.tagLength;
      }

      return new ParsedData()
      {
         data = reTag.Replace(data, string.Empty),
         tags = tagList.ToArray()
      };
   }

   class TagInfo
   {
      public int start;
      public int length;
      public int tagLength;
      public string name;
      public string attributeName;
      public string attributeValue;
      public TagInfo otherEnd;
   }

   class ParsedData
   {
      public string data;
      public TagInfo[] tags;
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
Apply color value=0x000000 from 0 to 76
This house is haunted. I've heard about ghosts screaming here after midnight.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apply wave from 14 to 20
This house is haunted. I've heard about ghosts screaming here after midnight.
              -------

Apply color value=0xFF0000 from 14 to 20
This house is haunted. I've heard about ghosts screaming here after midnight.
              -------

Apply shake from 47 to 55
This house is haunted. I've heard about ghosts screaming here after midnight.
                                               ---------
```

Comment: Oh man, that's some tough stuff. Thanks a lot for making it! I'm gonna need some time read it

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you a parsing method that you can apply not only to the case above, but to every case with a pattern cutting through the case. This method is not limited to the terms - color, wave, shake.

```
    private List<Tuple<string, string>> getVals(string input)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> finals = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();

        // first parser
        var mts = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[[^\u005D]+\]");

        foreach (var mt in mts)
        {
            // has no value=
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(mt.ToString(), @"(?i)value[\n\r\t\s]*="))
            {
                // not closing tag
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(mt.ToString(), @"^\[[\n\r\t\s]*\/"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        finals.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(Regex.Replace(mt.ToString(), @"^\[|\]$", "").Trim(), ""));
                    }
                    catch (Exception es)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(es.ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
            // has value=
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var spls = Regex.Split(mt.ToString(), @"(?i)value[\n\r\t\s]*=");
                    finals.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(Regex.Replace(spls[0].ToString(), @"^\[", "").Trim(), Regex.Replace(spls[1].ToString(), @"^\]$", "").Trim()));
                }
                catch (Exception es)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(es.ToString());
                }

            }
        }

        return finals;

    }
```

I also have an experience parsing JSON with a single regular expression. If you wonder what it is, visit my blog [www.mysplitter.com](http://www.mysplitter.com) .

Comment: It looks like you too are coding in C#. I noticed you used \u005D. But in my code, I was able to simply use `[^\]]+` instead of `[^\u005D]+`. It might interest you to know that the shorter version also seems to work.

Comment: You are right, but I don't prefer using symbols inside the negative expression because of a few experiences - some of them didn't work when they were multiple.